# Send video with streaming support

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

How do I send a video with streaming support?
I tried it like [this](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/721):

```py
client.send_file(userentity, 'video.mp4', attributes=(DocumentAttributeVideo(duration,w,h),), supports_streaming=True, force_document = False, progress_callback=handle_progress)
```

And I got a video without streaming support:

[image: nostreamingvideo]

how do I get such a video? 
(with streaming):

[image: videowithstreaming]

Comment: share a link to a sample video that doesn't work, and make sure you checked with more than one Telegram client.

Comment: Link: https://pastebin.com/hUsA4MUh
or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

Comment: Nevermind, remove the attributes argument, let the library deal with it. make sure you have hachoir installed to process metadata too, anything else is a container issue. reencode it to something familiar like h264.

Comment: I'm re-converting the video using ffmpeg ... -c:v libx264 ...

Comment: I would recommend to send it with an official client, redownload it, and check the video information. Then use that same information with Telethon.

Answer (score 1):

The supports_streaming should be inside attributes.

Like this

```
client.send_file(userentity, 'video.mp4', attributes=(DocumentAttributeVideo(duration,w,h,supports_streaming=True),), force_document = False, progress_callback=handle_progress)
```